# Turn character YYYY-Q1 into date

Tags: r, date, date-format, reformat, as.yearqtr

I would like to turn a character variable formatted as YYYY-QQ, so for example `2010-Q1`, into something I can use as a date. I have played around with `as.yearqtr`, but haven't could only figure out the output format. I haven't been been able to define the input format though.

Edit:

Has also been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071733/convert-quarter-year-format-to-a-date).

Comment: `as.Date(zoo::as.yearqtr("2010-Q1", '%Y-Q%q'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the right format in `as.yearqtr` formula like this:

```
library(zoo)
x<-"2010-Q1"
as.yearqtr(x, format = "%Y-Q%q")
[1] "2010 Q1"
```